# Fiori Launchpad plugin

Tags: sapui5

​Dear Fiori Experts,

can one of you please advise If  there is a possibility to development a launchpad plugin with the oData? I have a requirement to develop a message on the launchpad which will be displayed based on the odata model.

appreciate your response. Thank you

Comment: Yes it is, it's no different from any other app. Just add the service to the manifest.

Comment: @jorg thank you, but unfortunately the manifest.json is throwing an error when adding the data source "error: Property datasources is not allowed."

Comment: Your error message says: "error: Property datasources is not allowed."

In your manifest.json does it say “datasources” or “dataSources” as mentioned in the docu here
https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/1709.002/en-US/74038a52dcd7404e82b38be6d5fb1458.html?q=manifest.json

Comment: @Jorg, sorry its ---- Property dataSources is not allowed.

Comment: @lampstand I just tried it and the webide does not complain about it. did you add it underneath `"sap.app"`? how did you make the plugin? webide has a template for it now.